# PHP MySQL Arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sql-order-by, row

I'm not sure I understand how arrays work in MySQL.
I had a table that has 1 column called "id", each row has a random numeric value for "id". (the rows are in order by the date they were put into the table (another column called TimeStamp)

So I may have:

```
//row#: id#
row1: 5
row2: 17
row3: 2
row4: -54
row5: 18
```

Now I can re-arrange them by "ORDER BY" and put them in ascending order by "id"

```
$table1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY id ASC") or die(mysql_error()); 
$orderedArray = mysql_fetch_array($table1);
```

So now I have an array ($orderedArray).. It should be like this right?:

```
row4: -54
row3: 2
row1: 5
row2: 17
row5: 18
```

The "id" column is now in order instead of the number after row (in my case you would see a postdate(timestamp) instead of row1, or row3, but I just used a "row#" naming system to make the example easier...

So I have this array... now let's say I wanted to print the third row of my ORDER BY themed array, (aka the row in my original table with the third highest value in the "id" column... What would my code be?

I assumed something like this (but it didn't work):

```
$row3id = $orderedArray['id', 3];
print $row3id;
```

Anyone know? Thanks!

Comment: You'd do this using MySQLs LIMIT to return only the third row, rather than retrieving all rows from MySQL and then ignoring all but the third

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` fetches first row on the result set as an array. Not the whole result set as array. See my answer bellow.

Comment: @Mark, thanks! That will make things run much smoother! I tried looking into limited yesterday and was confused but now that I know what I'm using them for it should go much easier today! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($table1)) {
    $orderedArray[] = $row;  
}

$row3id = $orderedArray[2];
```

PHP arrays start with 0 as the first index.

Also, `mysql_fetch_array` has an optional parameter `result_type` which lets you decide how you want your results returned. The default is `MYSQL_BOTH`, which is what is used in your case seeing you didn't identify the `result_type` so you have an array result with associative and numbered indexes.

See here for more info:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_fetch_array()` would give back a single row which is the first. For getting all of them you should do a `while` loop first:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  $id[] = $row['id'];
}
// Use
$result = $id[2];
```

In this case the array will work. And if you want get the third one you can use `mysql_fetch_row()` I think.

Comment: Should that be `$id[] = $row['id'];`  in order to `echo $id[3];`

Answer (score 1):

My solution :
 your SELECT is in array $orderedArray
if you want exactly third row:

$i=0;

```
while($orderedArray=mysql_fetch_array($table1))
```

{

if($i==2){  echo $orderedArray[1];   }
$i++;

}

not the best  but working for third row :)

Comment: I was thinking using a loop and catching the third one I just didn't know how! Thanks! :) But the other answers had some great solutions too, you should check them out!